# Is -age as in garage, mirage, barrage a suffix?

Tags: suffixes, french

So *-age* as in *bondage*, *message* is a suffix since it's active in creating non-Norman words such as *shrinkage* (with the Saxon stem *shrink*), *slippage* (Saxon *slip*). What about the more recent *-age* as in *garage*, *mirage*, *barrage*. Is it considered a suffix **in English**?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-age#French

Comment: Is this question about how we define "suffix"? If so, you should specify the theoretical framework that you're interested in.

Comment: If you check the etymology of, say, "garage" you will see that it is not formed from a root and suffix, but was adapted directly from French.  Same with "mirage" (though "barrage" is a bit more equivocal).  There is no English word resembling "gar" (with the appropriate meaning), so there's no root to attach a suffix to.

Comment: @Hot Licks I don't think that the fact that "gar" means nothing in English is  adequate evidence that -age is not a suffix. "mess" means nothing either, but -age in words like "message" has gained dependence as an English suffix. Of course garage, mirage, barrage are the only examples I can think of at the moment; there might be other -age words which are not purely French that I'm not aware of, which is why I can't come to conclusion.

Comment: @sumelic No. I'm asking whether the "new" -age is a suffix or not and that's it.

Comment: I didn't say that "-age" was not a suffix *in some cases*.  Just not in the case of "garage".

Answer (score -1):

Yes. -age is a suffix added to form garage,mirage,barrage

Refer http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-age

-age means

(1) a collection, set or a group {garage- a place for housing motor vehicles}

(2) a process or action or the result of an action {mirage - an optical illusion created due to atmospheric conditions like appearance of sheet of water in a hot road because of the scorching sun}

(3)a process or action or the result of an action{ barrage - an artificial boundary across a river that too to prevent flooding}

Comment: All the examples from the link you referred to only illustrate the "old" -age as in message or passage, not the "new" -age in mirage or barrage.

Comment: @Sudharsan What Vun-Hugh is trying to say is, if you have another source that shows meanings #2 and#3, then link to those as well.